# how to fix i think some thing wrong with the code

Tags: docker, ipc, geth

what wrong with it ?
do i do something wrong in here ?

```
docker stop blockchain-service
docker rm blockchain-service

docker run --name blockchain-service -d
 --restart always -v ~/ethereum/:/var/run/ethereum -e 
 GETH_IPC_PATH=/var/run/ethereum/ethereum-data.ipc -e 
 SQS_QUEUE_URL=https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/407151891480/geth-mainnet-transactions -e 
 MASTER_WALLET_ADDRESS=0xMASTER_KEY --log-opt max-size=100m --log-opt max-file=3 -e 
SQS_PAYMENT_REQUESTS_QUEUE_URL=geth-mainnet-payment-requests -e 
 FAKE_USER_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY=PRIVATE_KEY -e 
FAKE_USER_WALLET_PUBLIC_KEY=0xPUBLIC_KEY -e 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ACCESS_KEY -e
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ACCESS_KEY  -e
 ENV=prod -e 
EXPECTED_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT=1000000000000000000000 -e 
DB_PORT=5432 -e 
DB_NAME=endordb -e
 DB_USER=endor_admin -e
 DB_HOST=MY_DB.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -e
DB_PASSWORD=NO_PASSWORD -e 
SLACK_TOKEN=xoxp-14092887333-345643415810-495051526626-e
 2e61b404d4be9b0a7002ae01e25991a  407151891480.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blockchain-service
```

Comment: Please tell us why you think that something is wrong with the given commands and explain what your problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing an env variable after the SLACK_TOKEN?

I recommend to put all your variables in an env file and then use "--env-file